# Why a loop inside a tsql function executes only once?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

Given a CustomerInvoiceId, this function should returns a string of concatenated project-numbers. But, I don't understand why it returning only a comma, I guess maybe because it's executing only once.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConcatProductNumbers] 
(
    @CustomerInvoiceId INT = 0
)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN

-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @count INT = 0,
@i INT = 1,
@strProjectNumber VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @Ci_ProjectNumber TABLE
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ProjectNumber VARCHAR(50) 
)

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here

INSERT INTO @Ci_ProjectNumber (ProjectNumber)
SELECT pa.ProjectNumber
FROM ProjectsActive pa
JOIN ProjectsActiveInvoicing pai
ON pa.OrderID = pai.OrderID
WHERE pai.CustomerInvoiceId = @CustomerInvoiceId;

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM @Ci_ProjectNumber

WHILE @count > @i
    BEGIN
        SELECT @strProjectNumber = (@strProjectNumber + ', ' + ci.ProjectNumber)
        FROM @Ci_ProjectNumber ci
        WHERE ci.Id = @i;    

        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END

-- Return the result of the function    
RETURN @strProjectNumber 

END
```

However, when I remove the defintion of the function keeping only the statements inside and replacing `RETURN @strProjectNumber` with `PRINT @strProjectNumber`, it works. Any reason why?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Change your RETURNS line from "RETURNS VARCHAR" to "RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)"

Comment: Thank you so much. And this is the answer. But you commented instead of writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to get a comma separated list of Project Numbers you could consider using `COALESCE` instead of a loop.

```
SELECT @strProjectNumber = COALESCE(@strProjectNumber+',' ,'') + ProjectNumber
FROM ProjectsActive pa
JOIN ProjectsActiveInvoicing pai
ON pa.OrderID = pai.OrderID
WHERE pai.CustomerInvoiceId = @CustomerInvoiceId;



RETURN @strProjectNumber
```

Comment: If the ProjectNumber column can contain NULL, then you should filter that in the where clause:  And ProjectNumber IS NOT NULL